# why is cgminer slowing down over time?

Tags: cgminer, dogecoin

I noticed something queer about cgminer, when I first started using it I got an ok amount of shares, but over time that number has been slowly dropping. it's the same difficulty,same temperature,but slightly less wu/m. it runs under the same conditions software  wise every day(i.e. no extra programs are running,Windows is not updating,etc) but yet it's still slowly dwindling away. not by huge chunks like suddenly stopping, but in general it's receiving less accepted shares(still 0 rejected shares, so it's not just failing at calculating them)
why is this happening, and is there anything I can do to help it?

Comment: Over what time period have you noticed this? Hours? Days? Weeks?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a signal your GPU is slowly decaying away, or may have to do with competition.

What coin are you mining, and at what pool? I've noticed that as more miners with more powerful machines enter a pool, they tend to give partial results very quickly so the pool orders a work restart more often - lowering the number of shares I get. If your pool allows you to manually set difficulty then set it to a lower value: better to send some shares for a lower difficulty than no shares at all.

Comment: the pool I used seems to have the difficulty set to 20- unlike some other pools that fluctuate. looking closer the number of shares is fluctuating,but is slightly less than when I started

Comment: If your pool uses a const. diff. rather than a dynamically set one, could indeed be too much competition. Just in case, try checking the health of your card and then manually force the diff. down to 15 or 16, your shares ought to go way up but you'd end up being paid less - then try to find a sweet spot.

Comment: how do I manually set the difficulty?

Comment: Don't know how to do it either from the client side, or if it's possible with CGMiner :( For the pool manicminer.in you the difficulty is set manually from the server side, changing your account's config

Comment: that's what I figured, it seems like part of Stratum is sending the work size it thinks each PC should be doing and cgminer just reads it and reports the results. but I don't think I'd be able to read that part of the source code properly so I can't say for sure